# Php variable echo in Jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

How to put my php variable inside of startDate:'01-01-1996 ?

I want just like this startDate:'01-01-date' How to do that?

```
$curYear = date('Y');

<script type = "text/javascript"charset = "utf-8">
    $(function () {
    var date = "<?php echo $curYear; ?>";

    $('.date-pick').datePicker({
        startDate: '01-01-1996'
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Whoa.  Are you generating Javascript with PHP?

Comment: +1, I guess it's startdate.php

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
var date = <?php echo $curYear; ?>;
$('.date-pick').datePicker({startDate:date });
```

---

Updated after OP's comment

```
var date = '01-01-' + <?php echo $curYear; ?>;
$('.date-pick').datePicker({startDate:date });
```

---

```
$date = '01-01-'.date('Y'); //in php
var date = <?php echo $date; ?>;
$('.date-pick').datePicker({startDate:date });
```

Comment: the problem is it start with this day. I want to start it 01-01-year

Comment: Sorry What I mean is not working. The clickable button of my calendar was lost.when I change the var date

Answer (score 0):

What about this?:

```
<script type = "text/javascript"charset = "utf-8">
    $(function () {
    var date = "<?php echo $curYear; ?>";

    $('.date-pick').datePicker({
        startDate: '01-01-<?=date("Y")?>'
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's really a very bad idea to mix jQuery with PHP. Try to find another way.

If you need current year:

```
$(function () {
    var cur_year = new Date().getFullYear();
    $('.date-pick').datePicker({
        startDate: '01-01-'+cur_year
    });
});
```

If only php script can do it (e.g. if this value is stored in DB) you can use ajax

```
$(function () {
    $.get('path_to_script_that_returns_year.php', function(resp) {
        $('.date-pick').datePicker({
            startDate: '01-01-'+resp
        });
    });
});
```

where php script could be

```
<?php
// ...
// get your year and send
// ...
echo $var_with_year;
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to echo variable in javascript or jquery then you want to simply using one line code

`<?php echo $variable_name;?>;`